# Change style of XML defined SharedPreferences Activity, to match newer Holo style

Tags: android-layout, sharedpreferences, android

I have an existing Preference Activity (created using the standard XML style, and calling with the Preferences intent).

My problem, is this looks like the old style (2.3) preferences, even on 4.0+ devices.  I would like it to look like the newer settings style.  Is there some way to make this appearance change (perhaps applying a specific style attribute or something)?

I launch the Activity (note: using ApplicationContext, which I think is correct), in the following manner:

```
 final Context cxt = this.getApplicationContext();
 final Intent i5 = new Intent(cxt, Preferences.class);
 startActivity(i5);
```

The XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_notification_time" >
        <com.wolfsoft.dotd.util.TimePickerPreference
            android:defaultValue="07:30"
            android:key="notif_time"
            android:summary="@string/summary_notif_time"
            android:title="@string/title_notif_time" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_notif_onoff" >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="notif_pref"
            android:summary="@string/summary_notif_preference"
            android:title="@string/title_notif_preference" />
        </PreferenceCategory>
        <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_notif_category" >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="notif_game_pref"
            android:summary="@string/pref_game_notif_sum"
            android:title="@string/pref_game_notif_sum_title" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="notif_business_pref"
            android:summary="@string/pref_business_notif_sum"
            android:title="@string/pref_business_notif_sum_title" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="notif_entertainment_pref"
            android:summary="@string/pref_entertainment_notif_sum"
            android:title="@string/pref_entertainment_notif_sum_title" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="notif_lifestyle_pref"
            android:summary="@string/pref_lifestyle_notif_sum"
            android:title="@string/pref_lifestyle_notif_sum_title" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="notif_personalization_pref"
            android:summary="@string/pref_personalization_notif_sum"
            android:title="@string/pref_personalization_notif_sum_title" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="notif_local_pref"
            android:summary="@string/pref_local_notif_sum"
            android:title="@string/pref_local_notif_sum_title" />
    </PreferenceCategory>    
</PreferenceScreen>
```

My current screen looks like this:[image: current preferences screen]

I would like it to look like this:[image]

Comment: You want to change the style of the settings only? What theme are you using now?

Comment: Yes, I want my settings screen to look the same as the newer settings screen for Android.  I don't use any style for the Preferences screen, and only use: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"  for my Application (so no real themes that would effect these visuals I think.